# SOAP call by WebClient Content type 'text/xml' not supported

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, soap-client, reactive, jaxbelement

I tried to make a SOAP call from spring reactive webclient.

the `ConfirmPayer10`, `ConfirmPayer10Response` and `ObjectFactory` classes i generated from wsdl file by the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin.

for the encoder and decoder config, i get the same from [here](https://github.com/gungor/spring-webclient-soap/tree/master/src/main/java/webclient/soap/encoding) and [here](https://github.com/gungor/spring-webclient-soap/blob/master/src/main/java/webclient/soap/config/Config.java)

```
    ConfirmPayer10 confirmPayer10 = new ConfirmPayer10();
    confirmPayer10.setArg0(confirmPayerRq);
    final JAXBElement<ConfirmPayer10> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createConfirmPayer10(confirmPayer10);

    webClient.post().uri( url )
        .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        .body( Mono.just(jAXBElement) , new ParameterizedTypeReference<JAXBElement<ConfirmPayer10>>() {})
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(
            HttpStatus::isError,
            clientResponse ->
                clientResponse
                    .bodyToMono(String.class)
                    .flatMap(
                        errorResponseBody ->
                            Mono.error(
                                new ResponseStatusException(
                                    clientResponse.statusCode(),
                                    errorResponseBody))))

        .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<JAXBElement<ConfirmPayer10Response>>() {})
        .doOnSuccess( (res) -> {
            System.out.println("success");
            System.out.println("capital : " + res.getValue().getReturn().getRqUID());
        })
        .doOnError(ResponseStatusException.class, error -> {
            System.out.println( "error : "+ error );
        })
        .doOnError(Exception.class, ( Exception error ) -> {
            System.out.println( "error : "+ error );
            error.printStackTrace();
        }).subscribe();
```

the problem is that i have this error

> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException:
> Content type 'text/xml' not supported for
> bodyType=javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement< ConfirmPayer10 >

Comment: if you say "SOAP"...where is the "envelope"? https://medium.com/@EBingolIT/calling-soap-services-with-webclient-springboot-1b5e0df044cc

Comment: But regarding original exception message: try `application/xml` , get rid of `JAXBContext<XYZ>`, just try `XYZ` ...but when fixed (on client side), you need to conform with   endpoint (server)

Comment: @xerx593 when i tried the call using web-services it work fine, https://github.com/akanzari/MongoAutoConfig/blob/main/test